# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (1,)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, valueerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttvzM.png)I am new in coding and in using JupyterNotebook and I wanted to ask how will I graph x(as any time t)=(0,10,101) and y(as acceleration)=-2.2 . those are the values given to us by our professor but when I try to plot, it gives me an error and it says that ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (1,). thank you.

Comment: Please provide example of code you are trying to run in order to plot your data   so that other users could help you to define what causes this error

Comment: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0,10,101) t=x;
y=(-2.2)
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("acceleration")
plt.table('acceleration of the ball at time t')
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (1,)

Comment: Write more details on your question, but before anything please read the content of the help center on how to write a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Your description wasn't clear, I highly suggest next time you post to provide an example of the code that you are facing a problem. Have a look at how others frame their questions. Anyways I will try my best to help you.

We know that:

`x = 0.5at^2 +V0t`

Where:

*x*: position
*a*: acceleration
*V0*: initial velocity
*t*: time

In real life time is continous, however having an absolutley continous variable in programming is impossible, therefore the next best thing to do is use a range with a very small step size.

Let's start with assuming that the initial velocity is zero --> `x = 0.5at*t`

Now that we have simplified the equation let's tackle the problem of time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# acceleration is a constant variable
a = -2.2
# get array for the time
t = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
# calculate position at each time and store in array
x = 0.5*a*t*t


plt.plot(t,x)
plt.show()
```

**out**:

[[image: plot of position vs time]]

Above we calculated each value of x for the list of values in time, as you can see, in order to plot the values of position vs time, their the lengths of the arrays need to be the same. we can check the lengths of the arrays using the `len` function:

```
print(f"length of time: {len(t)} ")
print(f"length of position: {len(x)}" )
```

**out**:

```
length of time: 100 
length of position: 100
```

Here are some sources to help you get started with learning python:

- [Great free Course covering all the basics by Microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrxD0HtieHhS8VzuMCfQD4uJ9yne1mE6)
- [List Comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)
- [Functions in python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial)

Some channels on Youtube that I recommend:

- [Real Python](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI0vQvr9aFn27yR6Ej6n5UA)
- [Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5)
- [DataCamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Rf4fZDQ0yw&list=PLjgj6kdf_snaw8QnlhK5f3DzFDFKDU5f4)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to plot x versus y data you need to have matching shapes for x and y data.
So in order to plot horziontal line at y = -2.2 for x from 0 to 10 with 101 points instead of

```
y = (-2.2)
```

You need to use

```
y = np.full(101, -2.2)
```

Or better

```
y = np.full(x.shape, -2.2)
```

So that `y` would be of shape 101 matching `x` shape

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10,101)
y = np.repeat(-2.2,101) # map y constant value

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]